# Regain space from failed attempt to install Windows Using Boot Camp

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility

I'm kind of stuck with a 30GB partition on the hard drive of my MBP that I cannot regain. This is what happened:

1. I used boot camp to try to install Win 10 on a partition
2. Once it rebooted into Win10 setup, it failed to install the system on the partition
3. I tried to use Boot Camp Assistant to remove the partition but I'm getting this message:

> The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single
>   partition.

Then, I used disk utility to try to merge my main partition with the mentioned above but it won't let me remove it (I tried from recovery mode with the same results)

[image: Minus icon is disabled]

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.3 on my Late 2015 15" MBP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not afraid of the command line

First show your partitioning

```
sudo gpt show /dev/diskX
```

Remove the partition

```
sudo gpt remove -i 2 /dev/diskY
```

Replace X with your disk number, and the index "2" with the partition number of the windows partition.

Afterwards, use the gui to enlarge your partition.

Comment: You have to boot to another disk (or Internet Recovery Mode) to accomplish this. You can't simply remove a partition with gpt!

Comment: Thanks to both. I tried it from the Recovery mode and every time I got an error: `gpt remove: unable to open device '/dev/disk0': Resource busy`

Comment: run "sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk0" before? Maybe it got automatically mounted (or with force : sudo diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/diskX)